# good internal wifi card for new laptop (the installed one is not supported)

Tags: drivers, wireless, laptop

Which internal wifi card should I get for my new laptop?
(internal M.2 - [like this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Intel-Wireless-9260-2230-2x2-Gigabit-vPro/dp/B079QJQF4Y/ref=sr_1_2?crid=2E4ZG2UVPH33Z&dchild=1&keywords=intel+wireless+ac+9260&qid=1619342916&sprefix=intel+wireless+%2Caps%2C164&sr=8-2))

I've just got an acer nitro 5 (amd 5600h and nidia rtx 3060), after turning off secure boot it is mostly working well with 21.04. 1 nasty problem is the wifi chipset isn't supported yet (mediatek mt7921) (ubuntu 21.04).

Looks like the simplest option (apart from using a dongle which is inconvenient) is to get a different internal card - they aren't too expensive.

The intel ones are fairly common, but many people are reporting problems, so I'm just wondering which one to get. I don't need magic wifi 6, but would be nice to have for they day I get a new AP.

Comment: Site policy is to not recommend hardware.

Comment: well that's a bummer as this also applies to a number of other sites I though to ask the question on. I have yet to find one that will!

Comment: Intel but not a hardware recommendation Intel.

Comment: Find a USB wifi to use until your internal is supported.  I managed to break off antenna connectors off my M2 card when trying to swap, they are really easy to break

Answer (score 0):

USB WIFI dongles are great:
They are cheap.
They can be located as far as 5m from the computer thus avoiding the huge
interference source they represent.(even at the focal point of a parabola)
USB is standard for a lot of devices.
So both the dongle and the 5m USB cable are useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I just bought Acer Aspire 5 A515-56-555H which built-in with Media Tek MT7921 Wifi, but no driver available for Ubuntu.

I use alternative way that I bought a USB dongle "Comfast CF-727B" with Wifi 1300Mbps and Bluetooth 4.2 (2 in 1).

Ubuntu 20.04 able to auto-detect Bluetooth but no default driver for Wifi (RTL8822BU).

I am able to download, compile and install driver (RTL 88x2bu).

You may refer to this article:

https://dev.to/limal/install-rtl88x2ub-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-10-1ofp

If modprob fail with permission error, you may disable UEFI secure boot (https://vovaprivalov.medium.com/fixing-problem-with-missing-wifi-adapter-on-ubuntu-18-04-dec50879a47e):

## install mokutil:

$ sudo apt-get install mokutil

## check SecureBoot status:

$ mokutil --sb-state

## If status is "enabled" , you may disable with following command:

$ sudo mokutil — disable-validation

## Then reboot laptop

Now enter a temporary password between 8 to 16 digits. We will use this password later. Enter the same password again to confirm. Once it’s done reboot the system and press any key when you see the blue screen (MOK management). Select Change Secure Boot state.
Enter the password you had selected before and press Enter.
Select Yes to disable Secure Boot in shim-signed.
Press Enter key to finish the whole procedure. That’s all.