# WiFi option not available and WiFi card not detected in dual boot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, wireless

I'm a **complete newbie** in the world of Linux.
It was yesterday I tried to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 alongside my Windows 10, where the installation was smooth and I was able to switch between Windows and Ubuntu quite easily.
But then I ran into a problem. As you can see below, I have no option of WiFi available, so I tried looking into settings, to find the option of Wireless connections.

[image: Photo 1]

But again, I run into this, where there is no option to wireless connections:

[image: Photo 2]

So, I tried almost "every possible troubleshoot" provided online, but none of them were any help.

Finally after 12 hours of trying and not getting any outcome, I decided to post as a question here.

If you could help me out, it would be of a great use to me.

System Specs:

- Asus Zephyrus G14
- CPU - AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS
- RAM - 16GB
- SSD - 1TB
- Wifi Card - MediaTek WiFi 6 MT7921 Wireless LAN Card

Please understand the fact that I have literally negligible knowledge about Linux(sorry about that)
Thank you

P.S. I also tried using the `lshw -C network`  command, and I got this as an output:

[image: Photo 3]

**EDIT:**
Outputs for commands `sudo lsusb` and `sudo lspci` here

[image: Photo 5]

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lspci` and `sudo lsusb`? This will include information about your hardware, making it more likely that someone can offer a specific solution to your problem 

Comment: @matigo Done. Any Idea how do I approach now?

Comment: Uh, sorry, no. I think I messed up my kernel and I cannot boot into my latest kernel as I receive a new type of error now.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi isn't working because Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have a driver for
your Mediatek MT7921 wireless card.

Your options are:

- install a compatible driver
- upgrade to a newer kernel
- use Ubuntu 21.04 or newer

More detailed discussion and possible solutions here:

[Ubuntu 20.04 does not have MediaTek driver MT7921 for WIFI & Bluetooth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346617/ubuntu-20-04-does-not-have-mediatek-driver-mt7921-for-wifi-bluetooth)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
But, I think according to the link of a discussion you have sent, does it mean that my laptop's wifi card is not supported?

Comment: @IshaanDugar Your WiFi card is supported in newer kernels. See the other thread for instructions on how to upgrade.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see that. So, should I directly use this?: https://medium.com/@pjbgf/installing-ubuntu-on-the-latest-asus-rog-g15-36487ecea862

Comment: I tried using that thread, and now Ubuntu wouldn't boot up.

Comment: What commands did you run before Ubuntu stopped booting up?

Comment: @Adnan exactly as mentioned here https://medium.com/@pjbgf/installing-ubuntu-on-the-latest-asus-rog-g15-36487ecea862